# Difference between {} and {{}} initialization in Java

Tags: java

```
public class A{
}

A a = new A(){{
    final int x = 1; // IT HAS TO BE FINAL HERE. WHY?
}};

A aa = new A(){
    int x = 1; // THIS NEED NOT BE FINAL. WHY?
    final int y = 1; // STILL FINAL IS ALLOWED HERE. WHY?
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
};
```

Can somebody please answer the questions mentioned inside the snippet?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A a = new A(){{
    final int x = 1; // IT HAS TO BE FINAL HERE. WHY?
```

[It needn't.](http://ideone.com/tyGc7)

The difference between the two is that in the first case, you're writing the code used to initialize each object in the double braces. That `x` is its local variable (doesn't have anything to do with objects of class `A`).

In the second case, you're defining the classes body. `x` would be its member variable. If it were `static`, its class variable. If `final` a (basically) constant.

Comment: Is there any Java book that explains nitty gritty details of Java Language?

Comment: @ajay yes, it's called the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).

Answer (score 4):

The outer set of `{}` declares an anonymous subclass

The inner set declares an initialization block within that subclass.

With the following example, it becomes easier to understand what's going on:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("string");
    add("another string");
}};
```

You basically say: I want a subclass of List, which calls method `add` at initialization.

It's similar to:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("string");
strings.add("another string");
```

Comment: The inner {} is an initialization block, but is not _static_. If it were static, it would have the keyword `static` before it - but you can't have a static initializer inside an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder, why would you want to use the first version of the code (the one with {{}}). The `x` variable declared inside it's not useful at all, it's local only to the block scope in which it was defined, and being inside an anonymous class, you won't be able to reference it anywhere in the code.

And anyway, the first version of `x` declaration does *not* need to be `final`, it compiles just as fine, with or without `final`.

Comment: You would use the double-brace version because it's an idiom: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization Personally I don't think it's a very good one; it masks a surprising amount of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The first instance `A a = new A(){{...` has an initialisation block inside the declaration. Another way of writing it would be like this:

```
A a = new A()
{
    {
        final int x = 1; // This is inside an initialisation block
    }        
};
```

Changing the formatting makes it a bit more obvious.

Comment: Why does the static initialziation block not allow putting static final int x = 1 there?

Comment: the first instance doesn't have a static initialization block, it has an instance initialization block. you can put stuff in the block that references the instance (which is how the double-brace initialization trick works).

Comment: The inner {} is an initialization block, but is not _static_. If it were static, it would have the keyword `static` before it - but you can't have a static initializer inside an anonymous inner class.

Comment: @ajay: the variables declared there are local variables. so just like you can't have a static variable defined within a method, it can't go here either.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example the inner braces create something called an instance initializer. It's an obscure way to initialize variables and call instance methods when an object is constructed. So the first example creates an anonymous subclass of A and creates a local variable within the scope of the initializer. It doesn't have to be final.

In the second example you're creating an anonymous subclass of A but not creating an instance initializer, the variables you create are instance variables of the anonymous subclass.